# Web request performance really bad under stress

Tags: mysql, performance, flask, load-testing

I wrote a web application using python and Flask framework, and set it up on Apache with mod_wsgi. 
Today I use JMeter to perform some load testing on this application. 
For one web URL:

- when I set only 1 thread to send request, the response time is 200ms
- when I set 20 concurrent threads to send requests, the response time increases to more than 4000ms(4s). THIS IS UNACCEPTABLE!

I am trying to find the problem, so I recorded the time in before_request and teardown_request methods of flask. And it turns out the time taken to process the request is just over 10ms.

In this URL handler, the app just performs some SQL queries (about 10) in Mysql database, nothing special.

To test if the problem is with web server or framework configuration, I wrote another method Hello in the same flask application, which just returns a string. It performs perfectly under load, the response time is 13ms with 20-thread concurrency.

And when doing the load test, I execute 'top' on my server, there are about 10 apache threads, but the CPU is mostly idle.

I am at my wit's end now. Even if the request are performed serially, the performance should not drop so drastically... My guess is that there is some queuing somewhere that I am unaware of, and there must be overhead besides handling the request.

If you have experience in tuning performance of web applications, please help!

*EDIT*

About apache configuration, I used MPM worker mode, the configuration:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          4
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      50
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

As for mod_wsgi, I tried turning WSGIDaemonProcess on and off (by commenting the following line out), the performance looks the same.

```
# WSGIDaemonProcess tqt processes=3 threads=15 display-name=TQTSERVER
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the SQL queries that take so long? Most of the time indexing often used columns and tweaking query fixes speed issues.

Comment: But the request handling (including all SQL executions) finishes in about 10ms. I am wondering what happens in the rest of time - over 3900ms.

Comment: For worker MPM, you may not see much difference to daemon mode, but based on what you quote there, not sure you were running daemon mode. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Graham, Thanks！I will try the intructions in your article.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! You found the performance problem - not your users!

Analysing performance problems on web applications is usually hard, because there are so many moving parts, and it's hard to see inside the application while it's running.

The behaviour you describe is usually associated with a bottleneck resource - this happens when there's a particular resource that can't keep up, so queues requests, which tends to lead to a "hockey stick" curve with response times - once you hit the point where this resource can't keep up, the response time goes up very quickly.

20 concurrent threads seems low for that to happen, unless you're doing a lot of very heavy lifting on the page.

First place to start is TOP - while CPU is low, what's memory, disk access etc. doing? Is your database running on the same machine? If not, what does TOP say on the database server?

Assuming it's not some silly hardware thing, the next most likely problem is the database access on that page. It may be that one query is returning literally the entire database when all you want is one record (this is a fairly common anti pattern with ORM solutions); that could lead to the behaviour you describe. I would use the Flask logging framework to record your database calls (start, end, number of records returned), and look for anomalies there.

If the database is performing well under load, it's either the framework or the application code. Again, use logging statements in the code to trace the execution time of individual blocks of code, and keep hunting...

It's not glamorous, and can be really tedious - but it's a lot better that you found this before going live!

Answer (score 0):

Look at using New Relic to identify where the bottleneck is. See overview of it and discussion of identifying bottlenecks in my talk:

http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

Also edit your original question and add the mod_wsgi configuration you are using, plus whether you are using Apache prefork or worker MPM as you could be doing something non optimal there.